# Как решить задачу на JS на применение цикла и return

Tags: javascript

Напишите функцию, которая параметром будет принимать число и делить его на 2 столько раз, пока результат не станет меньше 10. Пусть функция возвращает количество итераций, которое потребовалось для достижения результата.
Моё решение:

```
function func(num){
let res= num/2;

for(let i=0;i<num;i++){

 if(res<10){
     return i;
   }
  }
 }
 alert(func(200));
```

Comment: num = num/2; внесите внутрь цикла и его значение проверяйте

Comment: MBo, СПАСИБО!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соответствии с задачей, цикл должен проверять пока делимое число не станет меньше 10

таким образом условие должно быть в виде `;num > 10;`

Кроме того, на каждой итерации нужно разделить число на 2, это можно сделать как в теле цикла так и в третьей секции.

А также необходимо увеличить счетчик итераций.

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```js
function func(num) {
  var i = 0;
  for (; num > 10; i++) {
    num /= 2;
  }

  return i;
}
console.log(func(200));
```

Comment: Grundy, СПАСИБО!))